# Upgrading GCC on Debian Wheezy to support C++ 11 features

Tags: debian, gcc

We are currently working with Kontron servers on which we've installed Debian 7.x systems.

I began to develop applications using C++ 11 features. But it's not officially supported by the version of gcc (gcc 4.7.x).

I just realized that it's not that easy to upgrade a version of GCC on a Debian 7.x.

1. What would be the best solution to upgrade the GCC version to a Debian Wheezy so that it supports C++ 11 features on my Linux dev platform?
2. What to upgrade on the production server so that the generated binary could execute properly? I guess the libstdc++ has changed a lot.

Comment: To upgrade g++ on wheezy, you'll also have to upgrade libstdc++ (and every package that depends on that) and many other libraries.  You'll end up with a system that is neither jessie nor wheezy but a custom-built hybrid of the two.  This custom distro will receive only a tiny fraction of the testing and integration that jessie receives (i.e. only what you do yourself).  You would be **much** better off just upgrading to jessie.  If your goal is to stay with oldstable aka wheezy then by upgrading g++ and libstdc++ etc you have already defeated that goal.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to compile it from source. I used the following instructions to update g++ on my Ubuntu machine, but should be the same for Debian. (You may use stow so that it is easier to remove later but it is not necessary.)

```
wget http://gcc.cybermirror.org/releases/gcc-4.9.0/gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.9.0/
./contrib/download_prerequisites
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/gcc-4.9.0 
make

sudo apt-get install stow
sudo make install
cd /usr/local/stow
sudo stow gcc-4.9.0
```

For more information you can read up on: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: I will test that solution tomorrow on my dev machine. What about the deployment on the production server ? Should I update some std libraries ?

Comment: let me know how it goes. Off the top of my head you would need to install libgmp-dev, libmpfr-dev and libmpc-dev